# Freemarker trimming right spaces not working

Tags: freemarker

I will be as simple as possible , i have the below `template.ftl`

```
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
FUER DATEI:                                                  ${content.fileName}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
BELEGLOSER DATENTRAEGERAUSTAUSCH
ERZ. SYSTEM:                                                   ${content.system}
INITIATOR:                                                  ${content.initiator}
DATEI ID:                                                      ${content.fileID}
```

**And i want to output** :

```
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
FUER DATEI:                                                             FileName
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BELEGLOSER DATENTRAEGERAUSTAUSCH
ERZ. SYSTEM:                                                             SYSTEMX
INITIATOR:                                                             Initiator
DATEI ID:                                                                 FileID
```

**But what i get instead** ... let's say for the above example is :

```
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
FUER DATEI:                                                            FileName
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BELEGLOSER DATENTRAEGERAUSTAUSCH
ERZ. SYSTEM:                                                       SYSTEMX
INITIATOR:                                                             Initiator
DATEI ID:                                                              FileID
```

---

**In other words the column is not properly aligned**

How can i fix this problem in FreeMarker :) ?

Comment: Is it HTML? can you use div?

Comment: @user7294900 It is just plain text file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer , i used something not very complex:

```
<#assign lineWidth = 80>
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
<#compress>FUER DATEI:                                                          </#compress>${content.fileName?left_pad(lineWidth-"FUER DATEI:"?length," ")}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BELEGLOSER DATENTRAEGERAUSTAUSCH
<#compress>ERZ. SYSTEM:                                                         </#compress>${content.system?left_pad(lineWidth-"ERZ. SYSTEM:"?length," ")}
<#compress>INITIATOR:                                                           </#compress>${content.initiator?left_pad(lineWidth-"INITIATOR:"?length," ")}
<#compress>DATEI ID:                                                            </#compress>${content.fileID?left_pad(lineWidth-"DATEI ID:"?length," ")}
```

So let's take the 3 first lines of code :

```
<#assign lineWidth = 80>
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
<#compress>FUER DATEI:                                                          </#compress>${content.fileName?left_pad(lineWidth-"FUER DATEI:"?length," ")}
```

**1.** Firstly i assign a variable `lineWidth` which represents the maximum line width of the file.

**2.** Then for each line i eat all the spaces using `<#compress>`

**3.** Then i added the `value` and left added the needed spaces in a way that everything aligns right.

----- **BOSS LEVEL BELOW - using functions** -----

```
<#assign lineWidth = 80>

<#function createLine prefix value >
    <#return prefix + value?left_pad(lineWidth - prefix?length," ")>
</#function>

B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
${createLine("FUER DATEI:",content.fileName)}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BELEGLOSER DATENTRAEGERAUSTAUSCH
${createLine("ERZ. SYSTEM:",content.system)}
${createLine("INITIATOR:",content.initiator)}
${createLine("DATEI ID:",content.fileID)}
${createLine("SAMMELREFERENZ ID:",content.referenceID)}
${createLine("RSTELLUNGSDATUM:",content.creationDate)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [<#rt>](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_t.html) for trimming right spaces

```
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
FUER DATEI:                                                  ${content.fileName}<#rt>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
BELEGLOSER DATENTRAEGERAUSTAUSCH
ERZ. SYSTEM:                                                   ${content.system}<#rt>
INITIATOR:                                                  ${content.initiator}<#rt>
DATEI ID:                                                      ${content.fileID}<#rt>
```

> rt (for right trim): Ignore all trailing white-space in this line.

Notice to add new lines between lines, for example:

```
B E G L E I T Z E T T E L                                                 Intern
FUER DATEI:                                                               ${content.fileName}<#rt>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , the problem now it is that it is skipping the lines brakes too , so everything becomes 1 line ...

Comment: For some reason it is skipping new lines like the second line combines with 3rd line .. I will add to the answer so you can see .

Comment: I just modified the question so it shows the outcome .... hm can you help me on that and i will accept your answer :) Why that possibly happens ?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I think you just missing new/break line between lines

Comment: I have even tried ${'\n'} right now .... it doesn't skip the new line but it also doesn't eats the right spaces . So i tried `FUER DATEI:                                                  ${content.fileName}<#rt>${'\n'}` This is madness :'(

Comment: Okay my friend i updated my question with your latest answer so you can see exactly what happens :) Let me know.

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Where from `______A` was added to question/template?

Comment: I added A (just a random lettter ) it to show you that it doesn't eat right spaces at all :)

Comment: I added a working answer after 3 hours :) It seems that it needs more work that i expected .

Comment: I will accept my answer below but will give you +1 because you inspired me :)